Solving Nonhomogenous Systems of ODE's with Linear Independence Issues via Undetermined Coefficients
been looking to better understand how to find the solution to the system $\vec{x}'=\begin{pmatrix}1&-26\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}cos(5t)$ using the method of undetermined coefficients, now given that the associated homogenous system $\vec{x}'=A\vec{x}$ has eigenvalues of $\lambda=\pm 5i$
I know the regular guess of $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}cos(5t)+\vec{b}sin(5t)$ won't work, I've also read somewhere that when this happens we try the guess $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}cos(5t)+\vec{b}sin(5t)+\vec{c}tcos(5t)+\vec{d}tsin(5t)$ which upon checking with Wolfram is in fact the form of the particular solution I believe in the end it's supposed to work out to: $\vec{x}_p=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{5} t \sin (5 t)+\frac{26}{125} \sin (5 t)+2 t \cos (5 t)+\frac{2}{25} \cos (5 t)\\\frac{2}{5} t \sin (5 t)+\frac{1}{125} \sin (5 t)+\frac{1}{25} \cos (5 t)\end{pmatrix}$
Now when I attempt to plug in the proper form of the particular solution I arrive at the following sets of equations $\cases{-5\vec{a}+\vec{d}=A\vec{b}\\5\vec{b}+\vec{c}=A\vec{a}+\vec{g}\\-5\vec{c}=A\vec{d}\\5\vec{d}=A\vec{c}}$ where the vector $\vec{g}$ represents the coefficients in front of the $cos(5t)$ for our non-homogenous term at the very beginning and which is equal to $\vec{g}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\0 \end{pmatrix}$
where I'm stuck is in attempting to solve the system of equations that is generated any help is greatly appreciated!

$a = (a_x, a_y), b = (b_x, b_y), \dots$, etc. Then, expanding everything and equating vector components, you get $8$ scalar equations for $8$ real variables, which you can solve using the standard techniques.

I have tried that @AlexJones, however, I run into some issues when trying to solve, for instance I get that the vector(s) $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$ can be whatever they please which surely can't be true based on the particular solution.

You should get some free components, but I believe they should be on the constant coefficients of $\sin$ and $\cos$; this is a result of the homogeneous solution being a linear combination of those terms, with the components scaled by the eigenvectors of $A$.

One can simplify the calculation rewriting the initial system as
\begin{align}
x'&= x-26y+4\cos(5t), \tag{1} \\
y'&= x-y. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Differentiating $(2)$, one gets
$$
y''=x'-y'=x-26y+4\cos(5t)-x+y
$$
$$
\implies y''+25y=4\cos(5t). \tag{3}
$$
One can obtain a particular solution to $(3)$ plugging the ansatz $y_p=At\cos(5t)+Bt\sin(5t)$. The result is
$$
-10A\sin(5t)+10B\cos(5t)=4\cos(5t) \implies A=0\quad\text{and}\quad B=\frac{2}{5}. \tag{4}
$$
Therefore, the general solution to $(3)$ is
$$
y(t)=a\cos(5t)+b\sin(5t)+\frac{2}{5}t\sin(5t). \tag{5}
$$
To complete the solution to the initial system of ODEs, one uses $(2)$:
$$
x(t)=y+y'=(a+5b+2t)\cos(5t)+\left(b-5a+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{5}t\right)\sin(5t). \tag{6}
$$

There are many ways to solve this, but I wanted to use your selected method of Undetermined Coefficients.
If we let
$$x_p(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 (a+b t) \cos (5 t) +(c+d t)\sin (5 t)  \\
  (e+f t)\cos (5 t)+ (g+h t)\sin (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Substituting $x_p(t)$ in the LHS, that is calculate $x_p'(t)$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -5 a \sin (5 t)-5 b t \sin (5 t)+b \cos (5 t)+5 c \cos (5 t)+d \sin (5 t)+5 d t \cos (5 t) \\
 -5 e \sin (5 t)-5 f t \sin (5 t)+f \cos (5 t)+5 g \cos (5 t)+h \sin (5 t)+5 h t \cos (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Substituting $x_p(t)$ in the RHS, that is calculate $Ax_p(t) + g(t)$
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a \cos (5 t)+b t \cos (5 t)+c \sin (5 t)+d t \sin (5 t)-26 e \cos (5 t)-26 f t \cos (5 t)-26 g \sin (5 t)-26 h t \sin (5 t)+4 \cos (5 t) \\
 a \cos (5 t)+b t \cos (5 t)+c \sin (5 t)+d t \sin (5 t)-e \cos (5 t)-f t \cos (5 t)-g \sin (5 t)-h t \sin (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Equating terms on the LHS to the RHS, we have the system
$$\begin{align} b+5 c&=a-26 e+4 \\5 d&=b-26 f\\d-5 a&=c-26 g\\-5 b&=d-26 h\\f+5 g&=a-e\\5 h&=b-f\\h-5 e&=c-g\\-5 f&=d-h \end{align}$$
Solving this system
$$b=2,d=\dfrac{2}{5}, e=\dfrac{a}{26}-\dfrac{5 c}{26}+\dfrac{1}{13}, f=0, g=\dfrac{5 a}{26}+\dfrac{c}{26}-\dfrac{1}{65}, h=\dfrac{2}{5}$$
Notice that we have two free variables (we can set them to anything we want), $a$ and $c$.
If we want to match the Wolfram result, we let $a = \dfrac{2}{25}$ and $c = \dfrac{26}{125}$

Your system is
$$
\dot x = A x + b f(t)
$$
with
$$
\cases{
x = (x_1,x_2)'\\
A = \left(\matrix{1&-26\\ 1&-1}\right)\\
B = \left(\matrix{4\\ 0}\right)\\
f(t) = \cos(5t)
}
$$
As the system is linear the solution can be obtained as:
$$
\cases{
\dot x_h = A x_h\\
\dot x_p = A x_p + B f(t)\\
x = x_h + x_p
}
$$
The homogeneous is straightforward: $x_h = e^{A t}c_0$. Now we will use the variation of constants method due to Lagrange, to obtain $x_p$. Making $x_p = e^{A t}c(t)$ and substituting into the complete equation we get
$$
A e^{A t}c(t) + e^{A t}\dot c(t) = A e^{A t}c(t) + B f(t)
$$
so we follow with
$$
e^{A t}\dot c(t) = B f(t)
$$
or
$$
\dot c(t) = e^{-A t}B f(t)
$$
in our case
$$
e^{A t} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t)+\cos (5 t) & -\frac{26}{5} \sin (5 t) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t) & \cos (5 t)-\frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
e^{-A t} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (5 t)-\frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t) & \frac{26}{5} \sin (5 t) \\
 -\frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t) & \frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t)+\cos (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then
$$
\dot c(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 4 \cos (5 t) \left(\cos (5 t)-\frac{1}{5} \sin (5 t)\right) \\
 -\frac{4}{5} \sin (5 t) \cos (5 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and then
$$
c(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 t+\frac{1}{5} \sin (10 t)+\frac{2}{25} \cos ^2(5 t) \\
 \frac{1}{25} \cos (10 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
hence
$$
x_p = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{2}{125} ((25 t+13) \sin (5 t)+5 (25 t+1) \cos (5 t)) \\
 \frac{1}{125} ((50 t+1) \sin (5 t)+5 \cos (5 t)) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Very clean write up +1
